# Telerik Kendo Grid "editable" property affecting anchor tag "Enter" keypress behaviours

Tags: jquery, html, kendo-grid, telerik-grid

While using telerik Kendo Grid, I was using the `"navigatable:true"` for navigating in the grid with the keyboard.

I have a column with anchor tags in it.

When the editable property of the grid is set to true, in that case, even after getting the focus, anchor tag is not opening new window with keyboard's Enter key.

But if editable is set to false, the same code is working and with Enter keypress, anchor tags are working.

My requirement is to have editable:true and grid's anchor tags should also be accessible through keyboard.

Please find these 2 scenarios with just "Editable" property changed in them:
[Link to UHoM/3](http://dojo.telerik.com/UHoM/3)
[Link to UHoM/4](http://dojo.telerik.com/UHoM/4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this by using jquery stopPropagation like this:
http://dojo.telerik.com/UHoM/8

```
template: "<a href='http://www.google.com' target='_blank' class='myLink'>#:FirstName#</a>"


dataBound: function(e) {
e.sender.element.find(".myLink").keydown(function(j){
if (j.keyCode == kendo.keys.ENTER) {
  j.stopPropagation();
}
```

});
}